# Table Layout inside Recycler view

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-tablelayout

[design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDh8s.png)

This is a recycler view design which i am working on.. In this, under Additional Info, I need to display a table [field and value in each row] which updates along with other data when user scrolls down and sometimes this additional info column is empty.. I tried adding table layout, i am able to count how many fields are there and add them programmatically inside table as rows, but i am getting remove view(ie.table rows added using tabayout.addView(tablerow) method) error when user scrolls.. Are there any alternatives to this? Or can i use some other way to implement this? Please help me..

Comment: It would be more helpful to show the relevant code that generates the recyclerview and tableview. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: ok andrew.. i will post the code here soon

Comment: Thanks Andrew.. sorry i wasnt able to provide the code within time.. But fortunately, i solved it.. Thanks for replying and guiding me in how to ask help...

Answer (score 0):

Well, You can design single layout for holder with border surrounded that layout's parent class and put that layout inside the adapter's bindviewholder which also surrounded by the border to make the whole view more graceful

Comment: Thanks Abdullah.. i didnt form the question correctly.. but i figured out the answer by myself.. Thanks a lot for viewing my question and providing an answer..

Answer (score 0):

In onCreate with activity or in onCreateView with Fragment. You need to remove all the views before adding new view as below -

```
 (YourViewName.parent as? ViewGroup)?.removeView(YourViewName)
```

PS - This will work if you are using Kotlin.

Below code snippet is for Java -

```
if (view != null) {
    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
    if (parent != null) {
       parent.removeView(view);
    } 
}
try {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.YourFragmentName, container, false);
} catch (InflateException e) {
  // catch exception
}
```

Comment: Thanks Priyanka.. i didnt form the question correctly.. but i figured out the answer by myself.. Thanks a lot for viewing my question and providing an answer..